# How can I link my flexbox css and html class?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to put some `flexbox` in my `CSS` on a class but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I have tried :

- create new class
- enter in a class from an other class
- put my flexbox on the container (make just horrible things)

```css
.footer li { /* I tried .footer a{}, .footer ul{}, footer{} */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-white">
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.auriol/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alexandre.auriol/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to apply some flexbox parameters in that class like: `row`, `row-reverse`, `space-between`. Just have some fun on this rainy french afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is applying flex in your list, in this case, `.footer ul`.

```css
.footer ul {
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}
```

```html
<div class="card-white">
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.auriol/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alexandre.auriol/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>Instagram</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how OP applied their CSS, the expected outcome might be something they didn't expect though. So saying that your solution is the "right way" is inaccurate, and before one can actually answer their question, they need to clarify what the expected outcome is. And do note, OP said they tried `.footer ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here ?
Why do you want to use flex on ul elements while ul already organizes columns?

If you just need practicing flexbox elements, here's the thing : you have to "display: flex" parent element, here `<ul>` and not `<li>`.

Here's a fiddle example.
https://jsfiddle.net/hog1mjs9/

Comment: If you use external resources, your answer need the essential part of the code sample **within** the answer, or else, when that link dies, so does the value of the answer.